# Music app that integrates well with Synology NAS

Tags: itunes, network, music, nas

I'm looking for music software that will work well integrating with a large (~1TB) music collection on a Synology device.

Requirements:

1. Fast searching
2. Fast connection
3. adapts happily to NAS being available/not available (no need to manually reconnect/reload)
4. keeping up to date passively when files are added to the NAS library.
5. ability to easily copy files over.

I have a synology NAS and I have iTunes Media Server running on it. It fulfills a number of these but fails pretty extremely at #1 and 2.

Comment: Pardon me for asking, how is that a Apple products question.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I want software that runs on OSX to access the NAS files. Although maybe this site is for things only specifically made by Apple, I thought it was for the general use of Apple products...